# How do Python Generators know who is calling?

Tags: python, generator

This question is making me pull my hair out.

if I do:

```
def mygen():
    for i in range(100):
        yield i
```

and call it from one thousand threads, how does the generator know what to send next for each thread?

Everytime I call it, does the generator save a table with the counter and the caller reference or something like that?

It's weird.

Please, clarify my mind on that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mygen` does not have to remember anything. Every call to `mygen()` returns an independent iterable. These iterables, on the other hand, have state: Every time `next()` is called on one, it jumps to the correct place in the generator code -- when a `yield` is encountered, control is handed back to the caller. The actual implementation is rather messy, but in principle you can imagine that such an iterator stores the local variables, the bytecode, and the current position in the bytecode (a.k.a. instruction pointer). There is nothing special about threads here.

Comment: Yeah, the threads was just to illustrate the problem. Considering that generators might give the wrong look of concurrency(or something more black-magic than that) to python beginners.

Comment: @PatrickBassut: Well, you can simulate [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) with them, and with coroutines you can make [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).

Answer (score 2):

A function like this, when called, will return a generator object.  If you have separate threads calling `next()` on the same generator object, they will interfere with eachother.  That is to say, 5 threads calling `next()` 10 times each will get 50 different yields.

If two threads each create a generator by calling `mygen()` within the thread, they will have separate generator objects.

A generator is an object, and its state will be stored in memory, so two threads that each create a `mygen()` will refer to separate objects.  It'd be no different than two threads creating an object from a `class`, they'll each have a different object, even though the class is the same.

if you're coming at this from a C background, this is **not** the same thing as a function with `static` variables.  The state is maintained in an object, not statically in the variables contained in the function.

Comment: You didn't quite answer my question. I don't wanna know what will happen, but how it happens. Does the generator keeps some value in memory when a thread creates a generator?

Comment: @PatrickBassut a generator object has a state just like any other object, so yes, its state will be stored in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It might be clearer if you look at it this way. Instead of:

```
for i in mygen():
    . . .
```

use:

```
gen_obj = mygen()
for i in gen_obj:
    . . .
```

then you can see that mygen() is only called once, and it *creates* a new object, and it is that object that gets iterated. You could create two sequences in the same thread, if you wanted:

```
gen1 = mygen()
gen2 = mygen()
print(gen1.__next__(), gen2.__next__(), gen1.__next__(), gen2.__next__())
```

This will print 0, 0, 1, 1.

You could access the same iterator from two threads if you like, just store the generator object in a global:

```
global_gen = mygen()
```

Thread 1:

```
for i in global_gen:
    . . .
```

Thread 2:

```
for i in global_gen:
    . . .
```

This would probably cause all kinds of havoc. :-)

Comment: generators are kinda weird. You can assign them to variables, but at the moment you actually use them it starts generating values in some sort of "on demand" way. If you assigned the memory location of a function, that'd totally easy to understand. But as far as I know, you're not doing that there(you're actually calling the function in gen_obj = mygen()). Wow!

Comment: When you advance to the next level of serious Python-Fu, you can pass pointers to bound __next__() methods as GUI callbacks. :-)

Comment: Most of the time, the "def" statement creates a single function object from your code, which is executed when you call the function by name. If the code contains "yield", however, the def creates *two* function objects: the one that gets called when you invoke the function name has none of your code at all; it just returns the generator object. The function object it creates from your code is called via the __next__ attribute of that generator object, and that function keeps its state in the generator object and knows how to save and restore it between calls.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation daniel. I understand it clearly now(although there's some other things I still have doubts that runs out of that questions' scope). Thanks!